# Transition delay seems to be ignored on "height: auto;"

Tags: html, css, transition

I know that I can't animate the height of an element from `0` to `auto`. And that ist fine for my case.

When you click the heading the element below should take up its space and fade in. When you click again, it should fade out and then disappear.

But: It seems that the delay on `height` is ignored. That means, it immediately gets height `0` and then fades out. You can see that very clearly on the red border.

Can someone explain why and what would be a good workaround?

*HTML*

```
<h1>Minion Ipsum</h1>
<p>[…]</p>
```

*CSS*

```
p {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.55s linear, visibility 0 0.6s linear, height 0 0.7s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.55s linear, visibility 0 0.6s linear, height 0 0.7s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.55s linear, visibility 0 0.6s linear, height 0 0.7s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.55s linear, visibility 0 0.6s linear, height 0 0.7s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.55s linear, visibility 0 0.6s linear, height 0 0.7s linear;
}

p.active {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.405, 0.145, 0.505, 1);
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.405, 0.145, 0.505, 1);
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.405, 0.145, 0.505, 1);
    -o-transition: opacity 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.405, 0.145, 0.505, 1);
    transition: opacity 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.405, 0.145, 0.505, 1);
}
```

*Test*

http://jsfiddle.net/4wqoaek2/

Answer (score 0):

That's because you can't transition with `height: auto`. When you change the height in your fiddle from `auto` to i.e. `20px` you'll see the transition working correctly. (Using Chrome 36 on OS X)

A workaround would be figuring out the correct height via javascript and apply that style to `p.active`.

Comment: or you could just transition the `transform: scaleY` property, like so http://jsfiddle.net/4wqoaek2/4/

Comment: @PeterVR: That's indeed the most elegant solution. You should add it as answer.